# Autodesk design automation API for Navisworks

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-navisworks

Actually, we have a plugin in the desktop Navisworks application.

I want to move this plugin over to the cloud in Autodesk Forge viewer. So Does Autodesk provide design automation API for Navisworks?

Answer (score 0):

At momemt the only four Engines AutoCAD, Inventor, Revit and 3DS Max are available on DA service.